# Rails 4.1 - Why Spring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spork, zeus, spring-gem

Now with [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) built-in with rails 4.1, I am curious about why the dev-team chose Spring over the others (Zeus and Spork).

Why did they choose Spring?

Comment: Question changed so that it is not primarily opinion-based.

Comment: it's still opinion-based, and the only answer is 'because the core team wanted to'.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are serious or not, but that sure is not a an answer to this question. Or maybe you are one of those people that likes to answer "because it is like that" on all questions.

Comment: Rails is a really opinionated framework, though, so it makes arbitrary decisions like that. You'll get used to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you read the README from the v0.9 tag of Spring it should answer your question: https://github.com/rails/spring/tree/v0.0.9

The highlights appear to be:

- implemented in pure Ruby
- makes use of Rails' built-in code reloader
- totally automatic (boots up in the background the first time you run a command)